# Xcode9 beta, can't create a new playground page

Tags: swift-playground, xcode9-beta

I can do this function via the "File->New" menu, but the new playground page never shows in left navigator. Who knows how to fix this bug?

Comment: It's a known bug. In the meantime, you could also open the playground with Xcode 8, add the pages, then go back to Xcode 9.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, it's a known bug in Xcode 9 beta. Unfortunately, there is no workaround for instant.

"The New playground page contextual menu item does not create a new page. (32164810)"

Comment: Incorrect. Playgrounds CAN contain multiple pages - problem with adding playground pages is a bug.

Comment: There is a workaround for this. Drag and drop a page from another playground.